# Nested JSON to Java Object mapping using GSON

Tags: java, jquery, json, gson

Hello I am stuck in converting JSON NESTED Array to JAVA Objects using GSON labirary.

Here is my JSON String

```
[{\"name\":\"3214657890RootSAPSSE\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"},{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"}]}]
```

I tested my code with `x="[{\"name\":\"MyNode\"}]";` and for this my java code is

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType();
List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(x, type);
System.out.println("hello "+l.get(0).getName());
```

AND EmployeeJSONObj is class

```
public class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    EmployeeJSONObj()
    {

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

This is working fine. But my this code gives me error when I change the JSON String to

```
[{\"name\":\"3214657890RootSAPSSE\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"},{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"}]}]
```

This is a tree. I want generic solution, which can traverse the whole nested json string. I'm stuck in the middle of a project. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Does it always have children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `List` of children in your class so that Gson can deserialize the `children` array. Here's a working example.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "[{\"name\":\"3214657890RootSAPSSE\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative\"},{\"name\":\"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão\"}]}]";
    System.out.println(str);

    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType();
    List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(str, type);
    System.out.println(l);
}
public static  class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    private List<EmployeeJSONObj> children = new LinkedList<>();
    EmployeeJSONObj()
    {

    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", children = " + children;
    }

}
```

prints

```
[{"name":"3214657890RootSAPSSE","children":[{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative"},{"name":"672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão"}]}]
[name: 3214657890RootSAPSSE, children = [name: 672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionCustomer Representative, children = [], name: 672BENIAMEEN .Sales Base Market SectionPeão, children = []]]
```

Comment: I think thi is not working for nested json - I mean My json is generating dynamically. So user can make as many child as she wants...

Comment: @user2777070 Provide an example that you think won't work. Each `EmployeeJSONObj` has its own `children`. It'll nest as many as it needs to.

Comment: When I give it dynamic JSON it gives me this error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2"

Comment: @user2777070 You're trying a different format of JSON than in your example. You're giving it an object instead of an array.

Comment: How do I get the stored objects in java from this code? istead of showing whole json string?

Comment: @user2777070 Add a getter for the `children` list and iterate through them.

Comment: I'm trying this and it is thorwing me error System.out.println(l.get(0).getName());

Comment: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2

Comment: @User The line you just said definitely didn't give that error. That's the same error as before. Make sure the JSON you provide fits the same format as `TypeToken` or class you provide to the `Gson` instance. Do some debugging.

Comment: Okay let me check it.

Comment: I recompiled the code and here is the error "Expected name at line 1 column 3"

Comment: @user2777070 Please don't give me the error without any context. I have no idea what you are currently working on.

Comment: Actually the json string is coming from HTML Hidden field. But when I get the string and give it to the gson it gives me error "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 2" Here is my Java code String x = request.getParameter("JSONString");  
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
java.lang.reflect.Type type = new TypeToken<List<EmployeeJSONObj>>(){}.getType()                                      List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(x, type);
     System.out.println(l.get(0).getName());                      If I give a hard code string to it , it works fine.

Comment: @user2777070 If the json you get is not an array, you can't use a `List` `TypeToken`.

Comment: Now I am getting problems while iterating them. Here is my java code to iterate the list. But it only iterate one level of tree. I want to traverse whole list/tree. "List<EmployeeJSONObj>l = gson.fromJson(xr, type);
    List<EmployeeJSONObj>l1 = l.get(0).getChild();
    for(int i=0;i<l1.size();i++)
    {
     out.println("Name: "+l1.get(i).getName()+"<br/>");
    }"